# Error 2042 When Using Vlookup To Find Date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, vlookup

I am trying to write code that looks up a batch ID based on the date entered in the "TSDate" field.

I keep getting error 2042 when trying to use the Application.VLookup Function in VBA:

```
'Timesheet Date

Private Sub TSdate_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As _
MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)

Dim TimesheetDate As Date
Dim batch As Variant
Dim DRange As Range
Set DRange = Range("Table_PayPeriods")

If KeyCode = 13 Or KeyCode = 9 Then
    TSDate.Value = Format(TSDate.Value, "dd-mmm-yy")
    TimesheetDate = TSDate.Value
    batch = Application.VLookup(TSDate.Value, DRange, 2, 0)
    MsgBox (DRange(2, 2))
    BatchID.Text = batch
End If
End Sub
```

The messagebox proves that the data being looked up is being pulled properly, the problem is I am getting the error in the "batch" variable.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: i bet it has a lot to do with that date format of mmm, or not i coul be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.VLookup` will return `Error 2042` when the lookup value is not found.

You need to test for error, and handle appropriately:

```
If KeyCode = 13 Or KeyCode = 9 Then
    TSDate.Value = Format(TSDate.Value, "dd-mmm-yy")
    TimesheetDate = TSDate.Value
    batch = Application.VLookup(TSDate.Value, DRange, 2, 0)
    If IsError(batch) Then
        'Do something
    Else
        MsgBox (DRange(2, 2))
        BatchID.Text = batch
    End If

End If
```

As for *why* the value is not found, it's not possible to answer without more detail from you regarding the input data and respective formats -- perhaps the value really doesn't exist, or perhaps it *appears* to exist but really does not: (generally I would expect a string will not match a date type and vice-versa).

If the cells *contain Date type values* (even if they are *formatted* to *look like* strings, an Error is expected. In this case, convert the string input (`TSDate.Value`) to a Date type, and convert *that* to a Long type and do the Vlookup with its long numeric equivalent:

```
batch = Application.VLookup(CLng(CDate(TSDate.Value)), DRange, 2, 0)
```

You'll still need Error handling in the event that the date value *literally* doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: I have fixed my code to give the error message, however I am looking to avoid the error altogether. Ideally, I would want "batch" to be a value looked up (a payroll batch ID in this case). The messagebox was a test to prove that DRange is indeed being pulled.

Comment: @Vietson then only handle the `If Not IsError(batch)` branch and call it a day! Either you deal with the returned `#N/A` error, or your deal with a (more VBA-idiomatic) full-fledged run-time error by using the early-bound version `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, which also gives you *IntelliSense*.

Comment: batch will return the lookup value *if* it exists, but not otherwise. DOes it exist? Please consider revising your question with screenshot/example data.

Comment: IOW, it's *impossible* to avoid an error value in `batch` if the value doesn't exist in the lookup range. But you can suppress it via boolean test with the `IsError` function.

Comment: I think the problem is with finding the value. If I were to enter a TimesheetDate of 1/2/17, I would expect to get a batch ID of 012017. The line MsgBox(DRange(2,2)) give me a message of 012017, which proves that DRange is being pulled (DRange is a 2 column range with Timesheet Dates in the first column and Batch ID in the second column). The problem I think has something to do with the Application.VLookup function and the format of the batch variable but I don't know exactly what.

Comment: No, I am 100% certain there is no problem with the VLOOKUP function, you are implementing it on mixed data types and a string will never match a date nor vice versa. See my revision above in the answer, for how to handle date values in the cells.